# how to get notification from server app to client app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

How to get a Notification? in my app (client), I didn't get notification from the server. Actually what I need is, created server app. It contains a list of orders using recyclerview items. When I try to update any item using contextmenu, it will show spinner contains 3 values (Placed, On my way, Shipped). After select and click 'YES' any one of these, it will send Notification to Client App. But I didn't get any notification from server while choose order status. Kindly help anyone.

## Server App

```
private void showUpdateDialog(String key, final Request item) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new
            AlertDialog.Builder(OrderStatus.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Update Order");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please Choose Status");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_order_layout,
            null);
    spinner = (MaterialSpinner) view.findViewById(R.id.statusSpinner);
    spinner.setItems("Placed", "On my way", "Shipped");
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    final String localKey = key;
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex()));

                    requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

## Client App

```
private void showUpdateDialog(String key, final Request item) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderStatus.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Update Order");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please Choose Status");
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_order_layout,
            null);
    spinner = (MaterialSpinner) view.findViewById(R.id.statusSpinner);
    spinner.setItems("Placed", "On my way", "Shipped");

    alertDialog.setView(view);
    final String localKey = key;
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    item.setStatus(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedIndex()));
                    requests.child(localKey).setValue(item);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: You have no code for sending or receiving the notification, if yes, then share it.